# Feature request of downloading the code excerpt

Tags: feature-request

Would it be convenient for people to be able to download the code excerpt of the OP (e.g as raw). It occurred to me once--and failed to respond to the answer-- not to be able to copy and paste the whole R code from the `code box`.

Comment: If there are any transcription issues; that is, if the OP left in bits and bobs that would make the script unrunnable, they haven't done their job in providing something that's verifiable and complete and should be downvoted for that. However, it sounds like you're describing something *slightly* different.  Do you have an example of this?

Comment: If you need a dedicated download feature for code, because copy and paste would be too cumbersome, then I wonder if OP really provided an MCVE or if that question is suitable for the purpose of Stack Overflow.

Comment: I understand what you all mean. E.g check this out. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44687247/twitter-followers-in-r . I mean I am eager to contribute but the code format gives a hard time (cannot do: CTRL+A, CTRL+C/V) and download e.g as in bitbucket the *whole* portion of code

Comment: At the very least we should get a small Copy To Clipboard button on code blocks, or at least a Select All button.

Comment: @Clonkex yup.  That is _at least_ what I am suggesting. Judging by the downvotes I believe it'll be a feature for the future for a long time.

Comment: @amonk If the OP is incapable of providing a snippet of code that illustrates the problem, why do you think they'd be capable of uploading the same snippet of code to be downloaded? If this turns out to simply be a 'copy' button next to the snippet, then it's a duplicate of [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/350982/snippet-copy-to-clipboard-or-to-answer-button)

Comment: @Rob pretty much yes we are asking the same question (and same timestamp? weird) . Ty

Comment: To all: I bumped into this https://github.com/MrMino/StackCtrlC .A-M-A-Z-I-N-G

Comment: [Ah yes, this feature is well-documented](https://i.imgur.com/SZPjHwz.jpg)

Answer (score 9):

No: Unclear benefits to users for non-trivial amount of work to implement the feature.

While theoretically this feature could be useful in reality it will be usable in one in a million case where OP not only created valid MCVE, but also made sure downloadable copy is working correctly.

Additional concern is such feature will encourage even longer walls of code posts with "just download and compile/run" from poster.

And a security concern - people would just try to compile/run presented code on they local machines. Even running basic non-malicious "why this sample does not delete all files correctly" code locally could bring a lot of pain...

Comment: got it. I am playing with  Python/R don't know how malicious these two can be...

Comment: *Non-trivial amount of work* is kinda harsh of a statement...my 2cents

Comment: @amonk I'm completely confused why you consider "Non-trivial amount of work" harsh. Since this change feels simple for you why post you've made has no details how it would be implemented? I.e. some rough description of zip content for top 20-30 language/framework combinations, suggestions on proper splitting files out of single code block, scaleability considerations, security, roll-out guidance (beta testing?), UI for web/mobile/apps... It is unfortunate that you decided not to  expand such trivial for you effort to make post better.

Comment: Seriously I thought you were talking generally about people in SO trying to steal code (via the suggested feature). Altruist I presume. Other than that I am not spending a μs of further meta.thoughts. 'nuff

Comment: @amonk I see... updated the post to clarify. (this comment will self-destruct in 10..9...)

Comment: I don't think I care if a user decides to run code on their machine without fully understanding what it's capable of.  It only exposes their skill level, and hopefully it exposes that skill level to their lead or manager.

Comment: @Makoto there are users who don't yet have lead or manager but still eager to help... "rm -rf \" is educational, but not every 13 years old can handle consequences easily...  (otherwise I totally agree with your statement).